# Не могу преобразовать String В Int

Tags: rust

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter the Celsius temperature to convert it to Fahrenheit");
    let mut celsius = String::new();
    
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut celsius)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    let mut i = celsius.parse::<i64>().unwrap();
}
```

Почему я не могу перевести Переменную celsius из String в Integer для дальнейших операций?
ошибка: thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src\main.rs:10:40
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

Answer (score 2):

Метод `read_line` считывает строку вместе с символом '\n' в конце, поэтому надо использовать метод [`str.trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) или [`str.trim_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_end):

```rust
let mut i = celsius.trim().parse::<i64>().unwrap();
```